# How to add Angular-enabled elements to DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to add some Angular-enabled DOM elements programmatically. Actually, I probably will need to add custom components. How can I do it?

Here's a trivial fiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJSz4/2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="add()" >Add</button>
        <div id="container">
            <div>{{test}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("main", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.add = function() {
        $("#container").append("<div>{{test}}</div>");
    };

    $scope.test = 'Test Message';
});
```

Just in case, I expect it to add a div showing "Test Message" for each click - not {{test}}.

Why do I need it? Well, I would like to have a few sortable columns (in jQuery sortable sense) with portlets. I imagine each portlet could be a component.

Am I climbing the wrong hill? What is the Angular way to solve this?

**EDIT**: I hoped this simplistic example wouldn't end that way, but anyway. The ultimate goal is not to display a div for each element in an array.

What I really want is a more complex controller. I need a portlet container with some interesting behavior. It may need to decide to place each portlet in a different column. It may offer changing the layout and have a decent way to reorganize portlets in such event. And so on.

Comment: did you go through the tutorial in the docs online ? you should do that first. You need to let your model drive the UI. if you need more "tests" , create an array of tests and add/remove elements. the view will update automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Although I am not entirely sure what the desired outcome is, you do want to be sure that all DOM manipulation is done within a directive and not inside your controller.

This JSfiddle example should get you going in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZJSz4/5/

```
<div ng-app="main">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div id="container">
    <button ng-click="add()" >Add</button>
    <ng-portlet></ng-portlet>
</div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module("main", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'Test Message';
}).directive("ngPortlet", function ($compile) {
return {
    template: '<div>{{test}}</div>   ',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, elm) {
        scope.add = function(){
            console.log(elm);
           elm.after($compile('<ng-portlet></ng-portlet>')(scope));
        }
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want multiple tests, I'd suggest setting it up like so.

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="add()" >Add</button>
        <div id="container">
            <div ng-repeat="test in tests">{{test.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$scope.tests = []; // define this as an array

$scope.add = function() {
   var newTest = {name: 'Test Message'};

   $scope.tests.push(newTest);
};
```

This will dynamically create divs based on your tests object.

Comment: I tried this but got `push is not a function`. $scope.tests should be defined as an array, not an object. `$scope.tests = [];`

Comment: @TravisHeeter lol, great edit. I took your edits as the initial. My apologies.

Comment: @TravisHeeter Also, 1337 Karma. Nice

Answer (score 0):

As @Christopher Marshall pointed out, the simplest way to do this is using a repeating element and pushing a new item into scope on the button press.

[HTML]

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="add()" >Add</button>
        <div id="container">
            <div ng-repeat="test in tests">{{test}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS]

```
angular.module("main", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.tests.push('New Message');
    };

    $scope.tests = ["Test Message","Test Message 2"];
});
```