# How to embed ng-click via javascript into an existing HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have got a directive defined called datatable. This is basically a custom template table which will be used application wide. The values for the columns are fed into it by a scope variable `$scope.getDisplayObject`. I need to download a blob file so need to modify the html on the go while supplying value for one particular column in the table. 
Here is the code:

```
$scope.getDisplayObject = function(obj, key) {
        var key = key.Fields[0].Key;
        var valueObj = { value: obj[key],
                         color: '#6495ED'
                       };
        if (key == "col_for_downloadable_link") {
            //Code to write the downloadable link. The blob will be the value corresponding to this particular key and can be accesses as obj[col_for_downloadable_link]
        }
        return valueObj;
  };
```

I have already tried following solutions:

```
valueObj.value='<a href="#" ng-click=download(document) target="_blank">Content</a>'
```

- Have tried compiling and appending via $compile but somehow couldn't figure out.

Please suggest a solution. Also let me know if I need to share more information.

Comment: Directives on dynamically appended DOM elements do not get recognized by AngularJS

Comment: See this link for how to do what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15843420/4987197

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the issue correctly, but take a look at this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zsIklpQUT72YoBBDg0rr?p=preview

```
<td><a href="#" ng-click={{item.link}} target="_blank">{{item.linkName}}</a></td>
```

If your html has on the ng-click a reference to a scope variable {{item.link}} it will update when you change the scope variable, updating the link (in the href, or on the ng-click calling a function).